# wso2-puppet variable scope

Tags: wso2, puppet

I'm trying to deploy WSO2 products using puppet (v 3.8.7, master/agent setup) and [provided puppet scripts](https://github.com/wso2/puppet-modules). Apart small details ( undefined wso2::hosts_template variable, usage of ensure_resource , ...), my fact tests are blocked with undefined template variables.

In my role definition I create a new products instance, e.g.

```
class { 'wso2am':

}
```

and I set a few facts:

```
product_name: wso2am
product_version: 2.0.0
product_profile: default
platform: default
vm_type:
```

which should install the wso2am with default settings

The error message is as follows:

```
 undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
(erb):25:in `get_binding'
/nix/store/xivrmfsyc7dc52m1zv1g52ziwjag5n4f-ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval'
...
 in ./modules/wso2am/templates/2.0.0/repository/conf/datasources/am-datasources.xml.erb at # SourcePos {sourceName = "./modules/wso2base/manifests/push_templates.pp", sourceLine = Pos 26, sourceColumn = Pos 10}
```

where I believe the template parameter **am_datasources** is undefined. Indeed I see in the **modules/wso2base/manifest/init.pp** the parameter is loaded from the hieradata, but the template parameters (am_datasources is only one of them) are never passed to the invoked defines (wso2base::push_templates) directly.

Does the script assume some environmental setup or extra data visibility?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you have `am_datasources` defined in `default.yaml` [like this](https://github.com/wso2/puppet-modules/blob/master/hieradata/dev/wso2/wso2am/2.0.0/default/default.yaml#L127).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I noticed the problem is completely somewhere else. Puppet 3.8. is in use which doesn't support iterations and loops. So no **am_datasources**, but the **each** function is not defined in our environment.

Comment: At the end - it's about the scope and variable visibility. The data are loaded in the product class and then a common base and template define is invoked. Apparently it works only for a specific range of puppet versions  :(